# Inverse Z-transform Problem

Tags: signal-processing, digital-communications, digital-filter, z-transform, equation

I'm rather stuck trying to compute the inverse Z-transform y[n] of the function below. I'm having trouble selecting the correct formulas from the table to achieve the right solution.

Any help with the solution will be greatly appreciated.

\$ Y(z) = \dfrac{1}{{(1 - z^{-1}})^3} \$

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do? Calcuate Y(s)?

Comment: I've tided the math for you but what are you trying to achieve?  Are you looking to find an algorithm to implement this in software, the response to a step input, equivalent function in the frequency domain Y(s)? What have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you just look into a z-transform table?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the inverse Z-transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly find the solution to your problem in common tables. For example, the table of common Z-transform pairs in the Z-transform wikipedia contains this equation.

$$ \frac{1}{\left(1-a z^{-1}\right)^m} $$ for positive integers m and depending on the size of |z|.

That's as close to your expression as it gets!

Comment: Does that work for a=1?